# CSS filter is not working in android 2.3

Tags: css, cordova

Using phonegap to build the apk which containts full page blur on swipe of menu. Its working fine on android of version 4.4.4 but not in 2.3. I used the following code

```
.blur{
   -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See here it says that the browser on android 2.3 is not supporting that feature:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: thanks, But that link shows 2.3 is not supported.Is there any other alternate method ?

Comment: No, the code is ok, but on android 2.3 that feature 'filter' is not supported/implemented, you will have to have android 4.4 to use it.

Comment: so is there any other method?

Comment: I don't think that there is alternative, try google maybe you will find something.

Comment: Blurring of the text can be emulated (kind of) using `text-shadow`. For images, you can make them 'faded' instead of blurring them, by changing their `opacity`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only blurring, can do it with jQuery library. In fact tries by default by CSS and falls back manually if it is not available.

http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/

Hope it helps.